# Let $X$ be a metric space and let $E \subset X$. Show that $E$ is the intersection of all its open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space and let $E \subset X$. Show that $E$ is the intersection of all its open sets.

I assume that this can be done by showing inclusion both ways, but have a bit hard time in formalizing what does this mean. Is it so that the equality can be expressed as $E= \bigcap_{i} B(x_i, r)$ where $B(x_i, r)$ is an open ball centered around $x_i$? The reason why I’m doubting this is that this would imply that all the balls would be of the same radius which isn’t necessarily true.

Comment: The language is vague, but the only thing that makes sense is $E = \bigcap_\Gamma U_\gamma$, where $\{U_\gamma:\gamma \in \Gamma\}$ is the set of open sets which *contain* $E$. Can you see why your open ball intersection is empty if $|E|>1$, and just $x$ if $E = \{x\}$ is a singleton?

Comment: The empty set is open.

Comment: The result is __*obviously false*__ as the empty set is an open set in every topological space. (I am surprised no one pointed this one out yet.)

Comment: @WillM.  I did point out that the empty set is open, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show that $E$ is the intersection of all its open sets.

I assume you mean "all its open neighbourhoods", to be precise.

> Is it so that the equality can be expressed as $E= \bigcap_{i} B(x_i, r)$ where $B(x_i, r)$ is an open ball centered around $x_i$?

No. In a normed space an open ball is convex. And it is easy to see that intersection of arbitrary family of convex sets is convex as well. But clearly not every subset is convex. And this is regardless of the choice of centers and radiuses. Thus this cannot be solved by open balls only.

The statement is however true in any $T_1$ space $X$ by two simple observations: since $\{x\}$ is closed then $U_x:=X\backslash\{x\}$ is open and given a subset $E\subseteq X$ we have

$$E=X\backslash(X\backslash E)=X\big\backslash\bigcup_{x\in X\backslash E}\{x\}=\bigcap_{x\in X\backslash E}X\backslash\{x\}$$

Note that $X\backslash\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $E$ for $x\in X\backslash E$. Therefore $E$ is an intersection of some open neighbourhoods. Thus of all open neighbourhoods (since every open neighbourhood of $E$ contains at least $E$).